# Find Temporarily Hidden Elements In Revit View

Tags: .net, autodesk, revit-api, revit

I've got a method that checks on some visibility issues in Revit. The problem is that it throws an error on an extremely common issue: "a user manually hiding the element in it's view".

This line of code

```
public bool IsElementManuallyHidden(View view, Element element)
{
     return view.IsElementVisibleInTemporaryViewMode(TemporaryViewMode.RevealHiddenElements, _element.Id);
}
```

throws an `ArgumentExceptionError` stating that: `"This view mode is not supported for checking element visibility."`

Anyone know of any potential workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - apparently, two more seconds of work found me a workaround :).

```
public bool IsElementManuallyHidden(View view, Element element)
{
    return element.IsHidden(view) || view.IsElementVisibleInTemporaryViewMode(TemporaryViewMode.RevealHiddenElements, _element.Id);
}
```

with `element.IsHidden(view)` being the key factor. I don't love that I can't check the Temporary modes though so if anyone has a better answer, I'll accept that instead.